# present perfect how to construct interrogative sentences?

Tags: present-perfect

For me the following two are identical.
Are there difference or they can be used interchangeably?

> How long **you have been** teaching English?
>
> How long **have you been** teaching English?

Comment: I don't think the two sentences are identical. The second one is a question, while the first one not.

Comment: related: [“… you have ever made” or “… you ever made”?](http://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/105801/you-have-ever-made-or-you-ever-made) and [(How many years) have you been married?/studying English?](http://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/14323/how-many-years-have-you-been-married-studying-english)

Comment: Also [Perfect Or Perfect Continuous](http://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/31897/perfect-or-perfect-continuous) and [“Have waited” vs. “did wait” vs. “have been waiting”](http://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/7818/have-waited-vs-did-wait-vs-have-been-waiting)

Comment: If you were writing in an English exam, choose the second version, (How long **have you been** teaching English?) each and every time. Yuri is correct that sometimes a positive sentence can be uttered as if it were a question e.g. You've been waiting here long? But, starting with the interrogative pronoun "How long" I really can't bring myself to say the first version. It sounds so bad, so wrong. It *is* wrong!